# Two-way binding on a WPF custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Apologies if this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

I am developing a music application (C#, WPF) that has an `Instrument` class and a `Note` class. The `Instrument` contains a list of `Note`s for tuning.

I have created a simple custom `NoteSelector` control that looks like the following:

[image]

My problem is that I can't two-way bind notes to the `SelectedNote` property of the control.

The code for the control looks like this:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_UpButton", Type = typeof(Button))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_DownButton", Type = typeof(Button))]
public class NoteSelector : Control
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (_upButton != null) _upButton.Click -= Up;
        if (_downButton != null) _downButton.Click -= Down;

         _upButton = GetTemplateChild("PART_UpButton") as Button;
        _downButton = GetTemplateChild("PART_DownButton") as Button;

        if (_upButton != null) _upButton.Click += Up;
        if (_downButton != null) _downButton.Click += Down;
    }

    public Note SelectedNote
    {
        get { return (Note)GetValue(SelectedNoteProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedNoteProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedNoteProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedNote", typeof(Note), typeof(NoteSelector), new PropertyMetadata(new Note()));

    Button _upButton;
    Button _downButton;

    public void Up(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedNote += 1;
        CheckUpDown();
    }

    public void Down(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedNote -= 1;
        CheckUpDown();
    }

    public void CheckUpDown()
    {
        _upButton.IsEnabled = true;
        _downButton.IsEnabled = true;

        // Check for minimum or maximum
        if (_upButton != null && SelectedNote.GetValue() >= Note.MaxValue) _upButton.IsEnabled = false;
        if (_downButton != null && SelectedNote.GetValue() <= Note.MinValue) _downButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }

}
```

This one-way binding works:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tuning}" Margin="0,-5,0,0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:NoteSelector Margin="0,5,0,0" SelectedNote="{Binding }"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But if I change to a two-way binding, I get the error "**System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:** 'Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.'"

I was only aware of this happening if the binding is to a field rather than a property, but SelectedNote is clearly a dependancy property, so I don't know what's going on.

I would appreciate any help with this.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like in `SelectedNote="{Binding }` you are missing `Path= PropertyName` such as
`SelectedNote="{Binding Path=PropertyName}`

Comment: The ItemsSource of the ItemControl is a list of Notes. So this should bind the Note to the Selector?

Comment: Binding should bind to object in your .xaml.cs. Lets assume you have main window and inside some `Note Selected {get;set;}` then you should bind `Path=Selected`

Comment: Yes, but since there's a list of notes (of variable length) in the viewmodel (`Tuning`), I want to have multiple `NoteSelector` controls, one for each. So I should be able to bind an ItemsControl to `Tuning` and then have a `NoteSelector` for each note. This is what I've tried to do. And why should only the OneWay binding work?

Comment: Please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892684/binding-a-string-list-to-a-datagridtemplatecolumn-textbox/. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Yevgeniy Thanks a lot, that fixed it! The trick was to use "Path=." in the binding so that the Path property isn't empty.